# Errors in 'com/badlogic/gdx/backends/gwt/GwtApplication.java encountered in HTML 5

Tags: html, gwt, libgdx

Recently I have come to know about this awesome framework i.e Libgdx. I am completely new to this framework and hence a few hitches are obvious. I have cloned the entire repository and I have also run gdx-setup-ui.jar file. It gives me 4 basic starter projects. (my-gdx-game, my-gdx-game-android , my-gdx-game-desktop , my-gdx-game-html)
The android and desktop project runs well, but, when I am trying to run the HTML5 project, after clicking on the URL link, I am facing this error,

```
[TRACE] [com.me.mygdxgame.GwtDefinition] - Finding entry point classes
[ERROR] [com.me.mygdxgame.GwtDefinition] - Errors in 'com/badlogic/gdx/backends/gwt/GwtApplication.java'
[ERROR] [com.me.mygdxgame.GwtDefinition] - Line 273: No source code is available for type com.badlogic.gdx.Net; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[ERROR] [com.me.mygdxgame.GwtDefinition] - Line 393: No source code is available for type com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Clipboard; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[ERROR] [com.me.mygdxgame.GwtDefinition] - Errors in 'com/badlogic/gdx/Application.java'
[ERROR] [com.me.mygdxgame.GwtDefinition] - Line 117: No source code is available for type com.badlogic.gdx.Net; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[ERROR] [com.me.mygdxgame.GwtDefinition] - Line 159: No source code is available for type com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Clipboard; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[ERROR] [com.me.mygdxgame.GwtDefinition] - Errors in 'com/badlogic/gdx/backends/gwt/GwtNet.java'
[ERROR] [com.me.mygdxgame.GwtDefinition] - Line 12: No source code is available for type com.badlogic.gdx.Net; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[ERROR] [com.me.mygdxgame.GwtDefinition] - Line 14: No source code is available for type com.badlogic.gdx.Net.HttpResult; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[ERROR] [com.me.mygdxgame.GwtDefinition] - Line 24: No source code is available for type com.badlogic.gdx.net.ServerSocket; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[ERROR] [com.me.mygdxgame.GwtDefinition] - Line 24: No source code is available for type com.badlogic.gdx.Net.Protocol; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[ERROR] [com.me.mygdxgame.GwtDefinition] - Line 24: No source code is available for type com.badlogic.gdx.net.ServerSocketHints; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[ERROR] [com.me.mygdxgame.GwtDefinition] - Line 29: No source code is available for type com.badlogic.gdx.net.Socket; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[ERROR] [com.me.mygdxgame.GwtDefinition] - Line 29: No source code is available for type com.badlogic.gdx.net.SocketHints; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[ERROR] [com.me.mygdxgame.GwtDefinition] - Errors in 'com/badlogic/gdx/backends/gwt/emu/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/Array.java'
[ERROR] [com.me.mygdxgame.GwtDefinition] - Line 342: No source code is available for type com.badlogic.gdx.utils.StringBuilder; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[ERROR] [com.me.mygdxgame.GwtDefinition] - Errors in 'com/badlogic/gdx/utils/ObjectMap.java'
[ERROR] [com.me.mygdxgame.GwtDefinition] - Line 468: No source code is available for type com.badlogic.gdx.utils.StringBuilder; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[ERROR] [com.me.mygdxgame.GwtDefinition] - Unable to find type 'com.me.mygdxgame.client.GwtLauncher'
[ERROR] [com.me.mygdxgame.GwtDefinition] - Hint: Previous compiler errors may have made this type unavailable
[ERROR] [com.me.mygdxgame.GwtDefinition] - Hint: Check the inheritance chain from your module; it may not be inheriting a required module or a module may not be adding its source path entries properly
[ERROR] [com.me.mygdxgame.GwtDefinition] - Failed to load module 'com.me.mygdxgame.GwtDefinition' from user agent 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/21.0.1180.89 Safari/537.1' at localhost:56812
```

Currently I am using libgdx version 0.9.7. My OS is Ubuntu 12, Eclipse Indigo.
Please help me out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having similar kind of error .. Just updated the Libgdx jar to the latest nightly build version, and problem will be solve.

Answer (score 0):

what are the jars added in java build path of your html project. Also check if gdx-sources.jar is present or not in your html project. Also in java build path go to  export tab and check is all the dependencies are checked or not.

Comment: Thanks @Pranav008 for showing interest. However I have resolved the issue. I updated the Libgdx jar to the latest nightly build. And guess what? It worked!!